# Models failing while trying to tune xgboost hyperparameters in R Tidymodels

Tags: r, xgboost, hyperparameters, tidymodels

I am not sure where I am going wrong. When I run the following the models within the tuning grid are failing. I get this Warning message: 'All models failed in tune_grid()'.
Any help will be very much appreciated.

```
# PREPROCESSING -- RECIPE ---------------------------------------------------------------------

library(recipes)

xgb_recipe <- recipe(EVENT ~ ., data = train_data) %>% # define target & data
  #step_string2factor(all_nominal()) %>%          
  #step_dummy(all_predictors()) %>%               
  recipes::step_other(all_nominal(), threshold = 0.01) %>%  
  recipes::step_nzv(all_nominal()) %>%    
  #step_downsample(EVENT) %>%                             
  prep()

> xgb_recipe
```

> Data Recipe
>
> Inputs:
>
> role #variables    outcome          1  predictor        272
>
> Training data contained 2427 data points and no missing data.
>
> Operations:
>
> Collapsing factor levels for PROGRAM_TYPE_CODE, PREFERENCE_NUMBER, ...
>   [trained] Sparse, unbalanced variable filter removed
>   PRIOR_PGRD_PRG_YR, PRIOR_TF_SC_PRG_YR, ETHNIC_GROUP_DESC, HASEMAIL,
>   ... [trained]

```
# XGB SPEC ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

xgb_spec <- boost_tree(
  trees = 600,                                 ## nround=6000
  tree_depth = tune(), min_n = tune(),         ## max_depth = 6
  loss_reduction = tune(),                     ## first three: model complexity
  sample_size = tune(), mtry = tune(),         ## randomness
  learn_rate = tune(),                          ## step size,
  #num_class=4,
  #objective = 'multi:softprob' #%>%
  #nthreads=20 %>%
  #print_every_n = 300
  ) %>% 
  set_engine("xgboost") %>% 
  set_mode("classification")


xgb_spec
```

> Boosted Tree Model Specification (classification)
>
> Main Arguments:   mtry = tune()   trees = 600   min_n = tune()
>   tree_depth = tune()   learn_rate = tune()   loss_reduction = tune()
>   sample_size = tune()
>
> Computational engine: xgboost

```
# GRID ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

xgb_grid <- grid_latin_hypercube(
  tree_depth(),
  min_n(),
  loss_reduction(),
  sample_size = sample_prop(),
  finalize(mtry(), train_data),
  learn_rate(),
  size = 20
  )

xgb_grid
```

> A tibble: 20 x 6    tree_depth min_n loss_reduction sample_size  mtry
>   learn_rate
>                                      1          4    15       1.71e- 6       0.256   110   2.14e- 9  2          7
>   29       4.08e- 8       0.836    97   2.07e-10  3         10    26
>   6.44e- 7       0.883    66   7.59e- 8  4          8    28       9.77e- 1       0.964   270   3.90e- 8  5          1    19       4.27e- 4
>   0.733   208   8.00e- 4  6          3     5       1.61e+ 1       0.392   220   4.04e-10  7          5     9       1.48e- 9       0.673   163
>   1.63e- 7  8         11    34       4.20e- 5       0.569   178   1.69e- 8  9         12    38       7.80e+ 0       0.143    79   8.67e- 7 10
>   4    12       5.58e- 9       0.946   173   1.17e- 2 11         14
>   2       1.30e- 4       0.805   202   1.10e- 4 12         15    21
>   9.15e- 3       0.454   134   3.82e- 3 13          9    21       4.99e- 6       0.500    10   2.91e- 9 14          7    17       7.60e-10
>   0.232   248   1.57e- 6 15         12    11       4.85e- 1       0.297    21   1.23e- 5 16          7    35       7.63e- 8       0.516    95
>   9.60e- 2 17          2     6       1.01e- 1       0.353    48   3.57e- 6 18         10    23       2.57e-10       0.161    33   1.46e- 2 19
>   13    40       2.00e- 3       0.715   150   3.44e- 5 20          5
>   32       1.25e- 2       0.610   234   4.95e- 4

```
# WORKFLOW ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

xgb_wf <- workflow() %>%
  add_recipe(xgb_recipe) %>%
  add_model(xgb_spec)

xgb_wf
```

> ══ Workflow
>   ═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
>   Preprocessor: Recipe Model: boost_tree()
>
> ── Preprocessor
>   ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
>   2 Recipe Steps
>
> ● step_other() ● step_nzv()
>
> ── Model
>   ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
>   Boosted Tree Model Specification (classification)
>
> Main Arguments:   mtry = tune()   trees = 600   min_n = tune()
>   tree_depth = tune()   learn_rate = tune()   loss_reduction = tune()
>   sample_size = tune()
>
> Computational engine: xgboost

```
# CROSS-VALIDATION Resamples  -----------------------------------------------------------------
 # 10 fold CV

set.seed(123)
cv_folds <- vfold_cv(train_data)
```

> ```
> cv_folds
> ```
>
> ## 10-fold cross-validation
>
> ## A tibble: 10 x 2    splits             id                        1  Fold01  2  Fold02  3
>
> Fold03  4  Fold04  5  Fold05  6  Fold06  7 
>   Fold07  8  Fold08  9  Fold09 10
>    Fold10

```
# TUNING --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

all_cores <- parallel::detectCores(logical = FALSE)
library(doParallel)
cl <- makePSOCKcluster(all_cores)
registerDoParallel(cl)


s <- Sys.time()
set.seed(2020)
xgb_res <- tune_grid(
  xgb_wf,
  resamples = cv_folds,
  grid = xgb_grid,
  control = control_grid(save_pred = TRUE,
                         verbose = TRUE)
  )
Sys.time() - s

xgb_res
```

> > xgb_res
> >         #  10-fold cross-validation 
> >         # A tibble: 10 x 5
> >            splits             id     .metrics .notes            .predictions
> >                                          
> >          1  Fold01     
> >          2  Fold02     
> >          3  Fold03     
> >          4  Fold04     
> >          5  Fold05     
> >          6  Fold06     
> >          7  Fold07     
> >          8  Fold08     
> >          9  Fold09     
> >         10  Fold10

Warning message:
All models failed in tune_grid(). See the `.notes` column.

Comment: perhaps this helps? https://github.com/tidymodels/tune/issues/60

Comment: Thanks for the link @sebasaenz, the fixes suggested there did not solve my issue. My models are still failing in tune_grid()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The xgboost algorithm is quite fussy about the data, must be numeric, perhaps worth checking.

In the absence of a reproducible sample of data with your code it is hard to be sure where the problem lies.

If the data is sensitive then just create some faux data.

Perhaps try running a small sample model without the parallelization to see if that isolates the problem.

Comment: The warning message "All models failed in tune_grid()" was so vague it was hard to figure out what was going on. I was running on parallel mode (registerDoParallel()), but when I switched to sequential (registerDoSEQ()) I got a more specific warning, and YES it was to do with the data type. Thanks for your suggestion @cousin_pete.